# Multiple methods named 'objectID' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes after upgraded to Xcode 11

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have upgraded my Xcode from 10.3 to Xcode 11 version, after upgrading my project not compiling and it shows the error :

### Multiple methods named 'objectID' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes##

I use the EncryptedStore library for coredata. 
when I compile with 10.3 it works but with Xcode 11 it shows the error.

Any idea?

```
- (BOOL)handleInsertedRelationInSaveRequest:(NSRelationshipDescription *)desc forObject:(NSManagedObject *)object error:(NSError **)error {
   BOOL __block success = YES;

   NSNumber __block *one, *two;
   NSArray *names = [@[[desc name],[[desc inverseRelationship] name]] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ VALUES (?, ?);",
                       [self tableNameForRelationship:desc]];

   [[object valueForKey:[desc name]] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id relative, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

       sqlite3_stmt *statement = [self preparedStatementForQuery:string];

       if ([[names objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[desc name]]) {
           one = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[relative objectID]];
           two = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[object objectID]];
       } else {
           one = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[object objectID]];
           two = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[relative objectID]];
       }

       sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, [one unsignedLongLongValue]);
       sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 2, [two unsignedLongLongValue]);

       sqlite3_step(statement);

       int finalize = sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       if (finalize != SQLITE_OK && finalize != SQLITE_CONSTRAINT) {
           if (error != nil) { *error = [self databaseError]; }
           success = NO;
       }

   }];

   return success;
}
```

Specifically I get the error on this part of the code:

```
one = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[relative objectID]];
```

and

```
two = [self referenceObjectForObjectID:[relative objectID]];
```

Comment: I don't think it knows what `objectID` is supposed to return.  Can't you provide a more concrete type other than `id` for `relative`?

Comment: HI @trojanfoe, I update my question and added complete code.

Comment: No, you don't need to provide more information to me, but to the compiler :)  `id` doesn't tell it much.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read it well :), the problem is, I don't know the type what return, I need to use id...

Comment: There is no other class or subclass you can cast `relative` to in that block?

Comment: It's not feasible for casting since there are around 1000s places to be changed...Any other suggestion?

Comment: I don't think you understand what *casting* means.  It would be one line at the start of that block (and whereever `object` is defined) and you would use the cast value in that block instead.

Comment: Thank you @trojanfoe, do you know, what is the reason in coding developer use id?

Comment: It's the most generic type in Objective-C that describes a class instance.  It's like `void *` would be in C++.

Comment: So if I don't what class instance I should use, I can't cast it....

Comment: I don't see how you cannot know what type it is.

Comment: Do you know, what type is it?

Comment: No!  It's input data in *your* code.  Come on man!

Comment: If knew what type of instance it is, I could resolved without asking question, however thank you.

Comment: No, I doubt that actually.

Comment: Since it is external library, it takes time to understand it the instance type, I wanted to ask someone if they have other solution. if you think that you can understand it very fast, please download from here https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/blob/master/Incremental%20Store/EncryptedStore.h. and write the right answer.

Comment: I can't find your code in the linked code. Which `objectID` method do you want to use?